# Muthuswamy Dikshithar's Nottuswaras and Western Music

Tags: classical-music, indian-classical

There are some songs called as Nottuswaras (from English *Note Swarams*) composed by Sri Muthuswamy Dikshitar, one of the composers of the Carnatic Music Trinity.

[image: Examples]

Source: Wikipedia

These are completely based on Western compositions.

I have a greater list actually:

1. Anjaneyam sadaa http://www.karnatik.com/c3326.shtml
2. Chintayeham sada http://www.karnatik.com/c3328.shtml
3. Guruguha padapankaja http://www.karnatik.com/c3332.shtml
4. Vagdevi Mamava http://www.karnatik.com/c3360.shtml

Anyone highly knowledgeable in classical Western music - please do tell to which songs these are similar.

There's an entire list [here in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nottuswara), but the examples provided are only those in the table.

If possible checking for the entire list would be very helpful...

Comment: Please ask this in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room). It's a great question, but off topic on the main site ("identification" question).